# Drools, spring and mule

Tags: spring, drools, mule

Has anyone combined these technologies? Could you share lessons learnt?

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a POC with these technologies and yes it is certainly possible but what I've learnt is spring beans are instantiated before the mule flow starts so if the mule flow is required to construct the drools rule fact a spring bean will not work. In my POC my mule flow builds the fact object in the payload which should then be available to the drools rule, although I've yet to get it running.